# Multiple backgrounds are possible for Panes and Charts in JavaFX, but not for Shapes

Tags: java, javafx

Recently, i learned that [applying multiple backgrounds in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_backgrounds_and_borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds) is possible. I tried to do the same with JavaFX CSS (OpenJFX 20.0.1). I defined two distinct linear gradients, one horizontally changing from #00000000 to #ff000088 (translucent red), the other vertically changing from #00000000 to #0000ff88 (translucent blue). I apply both the gradients simultaneously to four objects in a `GridPane`: a `Pane`, a `LineChart`, a `Button` and a `Rectangle`.

Since `Pane`, `LineChart` and `Button` are children of `Region`, they inherit the CSS property **-fx-background-color**, whereas `Rectangle` does not. Setting `Rectangle` fill paint is possible both through using `Rectangle`'s setFill() method, or CSS property ***-fx-fill***. Finally, the following code applies the mentioned two linear gradients to each and every of the four objects:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Test15 extends Application {

    public static void setSize(Region region, double width, double height) {
        region.setMaxSize(width, height);
        region.setPrefSize(width, height);
        region.setMinSize(width, height);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        // Initialize and show the main canvas.
        GridPane container = new GridPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(container);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // Instantiate a Pane, a LineChart and two Shapes (a Rectangle and a Circle).
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        Button button = new Button();

        // Add some labels for better addressing the Objects.
        double fontSize = 30;
        Label label1 = new Label("Pane");
        Label label2 = new Label("LineChart");
        Label label3 = new Label("Button");
        Label label4 = new Label("Rectangle :(");
        label1.setFont(new Font(fontSize));
        label2.setFont(new Font(fontSize));
        label3.setFont(new Font(fontSize));
        label4.setFont(new Font(fontSize));

        // Add the aforementioned objects into main canvas.
        container.addRow(0, label1, label2, label3, label4);
        container.addRow(1, pane, lineChart, button, rectangle);

        // Insert some arbitrary data into LineChart.
        lineChart.getData().add(new XYChart.Series<>());
        lineChart.getData().get(0).getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(1, 4));
        lineChart.getData().get(0).getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(2, 2));
        lineChart.getData().get(0).getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(3, 3));
        lineChart.getData().get(0).getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(4, 1));

        // Set sizes.
        setSize(pane, 200, 200);
        setSize(lineChart, 200, 200);
        setSize(button, 200, 200);
        rectangle.setWidth(200);
        rectangle.setHeight(200);


        // Apply a style to the Pane, LineChart, Button and Rectangle.
        String style = "linear-gradient(from 0.0% 0.0% to 100.0% 0.0%, #00000000 0.0%, #ff000088 100.0%)," +
                "linear-gradient(from 0.0% 0.0% to 0.0% 100.0%, #00000000 0.0%, #0000ff88 100.0%)";
        pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + style);
        lineChart.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + style);
        button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + style);

        // Here, I have a problem :(
        rectangle.setStyle("-fx-fill: " + style);


    }


}
```

I *expected* to run the program, only to see

[image]

while what I *actually* see is:

[image]

meaning that in the case of `Shape` class and its children, only the first gradient in the style is applied. It seems as though the property **-fx-fill** is not as competent as **-fx-background-color** in rendering multiple backgrounds. The question is clear:

> **Question:** How can I apply multiple backgrounds (or `Paint`s including `Color`s, `LinearGradient`s, `RadialGradient`s and `ImagePattern`s) to the children of `Shape` class using JavaFX CSS?

Comment: Paint doesn't support multiple gradients.  You would probably have to create your own custom Node with two Shapes on top of each other, each having one gradient.  Or just put two shapes on top of each other in your layout.

Comment: [`Region`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) has an `-fx-shape` attribute. You can define an SVG path for the region and use multiple backgrounds on it if you wish. It isn't the same as the Shape classes, but sometimes you can get a similar effect. It is how the `modena.css` default JavaFX CSS style sheet defines items like arrows in TitlePanes and ScrollBars, you can review it (it is in the javafx-controls jar) if you wish.

Comment: The `modena.css` that @jewelsea refers to is also available on [github](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css), which may (or may not) be more convenient.